# Putting all the page content into a web user control is a good practice?

Tags: asp.net, coding-style

In my company, within all the existing projects, they put the page contents and controls inside of a user control (Asp.NET) and then put the user control on the page.

Could there be any good reasons besides user-controls can be used put on the other pages fact? They also reach some properties and methods of the user-controls from the actual page.

- Controls

  - Login.ascx
- Login.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever asked somebody from your company why they do that?

Comment: I don't want as long as I cannot come up with a better solution or at least I don't know have any basic knowledge about at least why they could follow that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that technique used in place of master pages for systems built in 1.1 (before master pages), but in general I don't think that's a very sensible design. It seems like it would make the system more convoluted than it needs to be, and there are almost no incentives to justify it.

Another problem with this design is that it makes user controls more difficult to use in the traditional sense, because you can't nest controls of the same assembly within each other, at least not when the user controls are registered in the web.config. Any nested cotnrols would have to be created programmatically in the code behind or registered in the directive of each page that uses the control, which creates more redundancy and more convolusion.

The big question is why? What are you really gaining from this approach?

- Is the design more flexible?
- Is the system faster?
- Is the design easier to understand?
- Is the design easier to maintain?
- Is there less code required?

The answer to all of these questions is no, which to me clearly indicates that the design is lacking. This technique doesn't help the design, but hinders it. And for what reason? I can't think of one substantial benefit.

Hope this helps. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is the flip where a page with multiple user controls has the logic for each control in a separate file rather than all cluttered up in one code behind file,e.g. imagine the code within a handful of controls squished together in one file.  If you haven't seen spaghetti code that is an overloaded code behind doing too much in one file be thankful.  I've seen plenty of them.

Comment: That makes sense. But actually it seems they didn't even use two user-controls in the same page and that's why it looks unnecessary to me but maybe for further development they left the door open.